# Clicking on Browser back button causing 'Document Expired issue'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have one aspx page on which Usercontrol has called which has following code
Script:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.error-load').hide();
        $('#imgLoading').hide();
        $("#BtnLoadMore").click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            var lastArticleId = $('#hdnLastArticle').val();
            var sortOrder = $('#<%= hdnSortValue.ClientID  %>').val();
            $('#imgLoading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"RowId":"' + lastArticleId + '", "SortOrder":"' + sortOrder + '"}',
                url: "http://blogs.sample.com/themes/blogs/vitalvotes/LoadService.aspx/GetNextData",
                dataType: "json",
                success: RenderPagedData,
                error: function (response) {
                    $('.error-load').show();
                    $('#imgLoading').hide();
                }
            });

        });

    });

    function RenderPagedData(data) {

        var result = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var htmlString = null;
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            htmlString = "<tr><td><div class='current-articles'><div class='current-thumb'><a ";
            htmlString += "href='" + result[i].ArticleLink + "'";
            htmlString += "rel='nofollow'><img src='" + result[i].ThumbnailImage + "'style='height:135px;width:186px;border-width:0px;'>";
            htmlString += "</a></div><div class='current-list'><h2>";
            htmlString += "<a ";
            htmlString += "href='" + result[i].ArticleLink + "'>";
            htmlString += "" + result[i].Subject + "</a></h2><div class='views-comments'><h5>";
            htmlString += "<span style='color:Gray;'>" + result[i].NewsletterDate + "</span>";
            htmlString += "<span class='gray'>|</span> <span><span>";
            htmlString += "" + result[i].ViewCount + " Views </span></a></span></h5></div>";
            htmlString += "<span>" + result[i].Body + "</span>";
            htmlString += "</div><div class='clear'></div></div><div class='hr'></div></td></tr>";
            $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_bcr_bcr_bcr_BlogsPostForDefault_gvBlogsPost tr:last').after(htmlString);
            if (i == result.length - 1) {
                $('#hdnLastArticle').val(result[i].RowId);
            }
            $('#imgLoading').hide();
            $('#lblLoadError').hide();
            $("#BtnLoadMore").show();
        }


    }
</script>
```

Design:-

```
<radAjax:RadAjaxPanel ID="Panel" runat="server LoadingPanelID="Loadingpanel6">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSortValue" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="current-btns" style="float: left !important;">
        <div id="divFitnessSortBy" runat="server" class="fit-sort">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Sort by :</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMostRecent" Text="Most Recent" class="button action sortcomments"
                            runat="server" OnCommand="btnMostRecent_Click" CommandArgument="date" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMostViewed" Text="Most Viewed" class="Comments" runat="server"
                            OnCommand="btnMostViewed_Click" CommandArgument="views" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr">
    </div>
    <div class="BlogsPostHolderDiv" id="divPagination">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvBlogsPost" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PostID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="false" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="gvBlogsPost_Bound" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="current-articles">
                            <div class="current-thumb">
                                <a id="lnkThumbnail" runat="server" rel="nofollow">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgThumbnail" runat="server" Height="135px" Width="186px" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="current-list">
                                <h2>
                                    <a id="lnkArticle" runat="server">
                                       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Subject")%></a>
                                </h2>
                                <div class="views-comments">
                                    <h5>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewsletterDate" ForeColor="#808080"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostDate")%></asp:Label>
                                        <span class="gray">|</span> <span id="spnViews" runat="server"><span>
                                            <%#Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalViews")).ToString("#,#")%>
                                            Views </span></span>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblShortDescription" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Body")%> </asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hr">
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <div id="divLoadMore" style="text-align: center; margin: 5px auto;">
            <input type="button" id="BtnLoadMore" class="button action" style="float: none;"
                value="Load more Vitalvotes articles" /></div>
        <div class="error-load">
            Unable to load more articles</div>
        <div align="center">
            <img id="imgLoading" visible="false" alt="Loading" src="http://media.sample.com/Assets/images/text.gif" /></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLastArticle" value="10" />
    <radAjax:AjaxLoadingPanel ID="Loadingpanel6" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="Loading" BorderWidth="0px" ImageUrl="/themes/article/images/loading6.gif" />
    </radAjax:AjaxLoadingPanel>
</radAjax:RadAjaxPanel>`
```

When the page gets load initially the data gets loaded.with default button btnMostRecent and if i open any article and click on back button of browser it works fine. But, when i then click on button 'btnMostRecentit will load article and if i open any article and clickback button it shows document expiration issue`.Please tell me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you click the button it's actually posting the *page* back rather than doing an ajax call.

When a page is posted to the server form the client, if you navigate from the resulting page to some other page and then hit the back button the browser needs to send a post again in order to re-generate that page and so it displays the 'Document Expired' message.  Different browsers handle this differently.  Some will ask if you want to post the form again.  Either way it's often undesirable because it confuses the website visitor.

Anyway the "industry standard solution" to fix this is something called the "post redirect get" pattern.  In this approach, when you click a button that does an http post to the server, you have the server side code do a response redirect to the same page (causing an http get) with the parameters passed in the query string typically.

Since the page is ultimately rendered based on an http get rather than an http post, if you navigate from the page via a link and then use the back button to return it, the browser can just get the page again and there will be no 'Document Expired issue' or prompt to repost the form.

Comment: Thanks can you provide code snippet so that i can make changes accordingly in code

Comment: Sorry,  it's more of a design approach that is accomplished via code on the front end and backend so it's hard to give a short code snipit. As an alternate approach you could have the button click do an Ajax post rather then a regular form post.

Comment: @svs Please remember to accept my answer if it answered your question.